# Submodule shared across several projects

Tags: eclipse, git, git-submodules

I have a large number of projects in Git that depend upon each other.
Each of these projects addresses a different concern and corresponds to a different git repository.
In the end, my project architectures wind up having quite a bit of inheritance and I'd like to factorize duplicated entries.

In short, my projects hierarchy can be viewed like this :

```
Project 1

Project 2
    \
     - Project 1

Project 3
    \
     - Project 1

Project 4
    \
     - Project 2
     - Project 3
```

So `Project 1` is duplicated (in regard of `Project 4`) as a submodule of both `Project 2` and `Project 3`.

Moreover : in Eclipse, I can only import `Project 1` one time, so I must choose and then dependencies may have to be updated (for example Android plugin for Eclipse ADT, hard codes path to library project, using relative path :s).

And even worse, changes made to the project i imported, modify the repository from which it was imported, so to have a 'synchronized' workspace, i must commit modifications, then push them and pull them in the second repository whose project could not be imported.

---

Does anyone have a solution for such a problem ?
What i would like, would be something like that :

```
aFolder
    \
     - Project 1
     - Project 2 --> has submodule Project 1
     - Project 3 --> has submodule Project 1
     - Project 4 --> has submodule Project 2 and Project 3
```

So this way, `Project 2` and `Project 3` point to the same repository, which is then imported only once in Eclipse and always synchronized.

Unfortunately, git does not permit to create a submodule using path `../mySubmodule` because `../` is outside the repository ...

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need and had to reorganize my repositories.

I use Visual Studio instead of eclipse so I want to clarify the terms I use.

In VS a "solution" consists of 1+ "project" and configuration stuff (like dependencies).
A "project" is a collection of units that produce a dll or exe.

A layout of repositories would look like this:

```
solution "Solution 1" [repository]
    -> project "Project 1"  [submodule]

solution "Solution 2" [repository]
    -> project "Project 1"  [submodule]
    -> project "Project 2"  [submodule]
    (dependency "Project 2" depends on "Project 1" is stored directly in "Solution 2")

solution "Solution 3" [repository]
    -> project "Project 1"  [submodule]
    -> project "Project 3"  [submodule]
    (dependency "Project 3" depends on "Project 1" is stored directly in "Solution 3")

solution "Solution 4" [repository]
    -> project "Project 1"  [submodule]
    -> project "Project 2"  [submodule]
    -> project "Project 3"  [submodule]
    (dependency "Project 2" depends on "Project 1" is stored directly in "Solution 4")
    (dependency "Project 3" depends on "Project 1" is stored directly in "Solution 4")
```

So you end up with twice the amount of repositories:

- "Project 1"
- "Project 2"
- "Project 3"
- "Project 4"
- "Solution 1"
- "Solution 2"
- "Solution 3"
- "Solution 4"

The repository with the code and a "holder" repository consisting of dependencies and the code as a submodule.

Comment: I don't clearly understand your response. Is it a response ? As i understand, you encountered the same problem and you're looking for a solution too, is that it ?

Comment: No. I found a solution by organizing my repositories in the way I described above. I hope the layout of repositories that worked for VS are also applicable to Eclipse. Try to put the code and configuration files (containing the dependencies etc.) not in the same repository but the code in one repository and in the "main" project all dependencies and code as submodules. Hope this clarifies   my answer.